# Join SQL tables without changing the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables together using the code below but I want the rows from "tab1" to remain the same.

```
create table tab3 select * from tab1 left join tab2 on tab1.`tab1`=tab2.`tab2`;

Tab1
a
b
c
d
e
f
g


Tab2
a
a
c
d
```

but I got this result, "a" from Tab1 was doubled

```
Tab1    Tab2
a       a
a       a
b       b
c       c
d       null
e       null
f       null
g       null
```

I need this result instead where Tab1 rows remain the same such as the table below

```
Tab1    Tab2
a       a
b       b
c       c
d       null
e       null
f       null
g       null
```

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not terribly efficient, but you can use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct *
from tab1 left join
     tab2
     on tab1.`tab1` = tab2.`tab2`;
```

Or just on `tab2` itself:

```
select distinct *
from tab1 left join
     (select distinct tab2.* from tab2) tab2
     on tab1.`tab1` = tab2.`tab2`;
```